# display overlap/stacked background on hover

Tags: jquery, html, css

- I have a top bar
- I have browse on top bar
- When I hover on browse, I display black background
- I want to hide away black background, when I hover out of black background

I am able to display black background. Problem is while background is there, if I hover again on browse, then backgroud disappears and the appears again.

I dont want that. I only want background to disappear (once it is shown) when I hover out of it.

http://jsfiddle.net/z9Unk/226/

THE PROBLEM

- Hover on ITEM2
- Then hover out of ITEM2 but stay in black box
- Hover again on ITEM2   // here black box disappears and re-appears.

What I want

- Hover on ITEM2
- Then hover out of ITEM2 but stay in black box
- Hover again on ITEM2   // here black box stays...nothing changes
- Hover on out of black box
- black box disappears.

Please help.

HTML

```
<div class="item1">
  item1
</div>
<div class="item2">
    item2
</div>
```

CSS

```
.item1 {
  position:fixed;
  width:50%;
  height:320px;
  z-index:-1;
  top:0;
  background-color:black;
  opacity:0.85;
  display:none;
}

.item2 {
   position:fixed;
  top:32px;
  left:150px;
  color: red;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight:bold;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  z-index:1;

}
```

jQuery

```
$(".item2").hover(
    function() {
      $(".item1").fadeIn();
    },
    function() {
    }
);
$(".item1").hover(
    function() {
    },
    function() {
        $(".item1").fadeOut();
    }
);
```

www.vevo.com     // hover on browse on top bar....I want same behavior

Answer (score 1):

Well because you're putting both divs on top of each other , try to give 'Item2' some left and try again here :

```
.item2 {
     position:fixed;
     top:32px;
     left:200px;
     color: red;
     font-size: 14px;
     font-weight:bold;
     text-transform:uppercase;
     z-index:1;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/z9Unk/227/

Comment: oh now i understand , well 'z-index' would solve ur problem but the color will change , http://jsfiddle.net/z9Unk/228/

Answer (score 1):

use the `stop()` function.

```
$(".item2").hover(
    function() {
      $(".item1").stop().fadeIn();
    },
    function() {
    }
);
$(".item1").hover(
    function() {
    },
    function() {
        $(".item1").stop().fadeOut();
    }
);
```

Comment: this does not work. If hover in hover out b/w item2 and background...I can see issues

Comment: I see that you've changed your approach. Just to clarify, the above fiddle was modified, and then the answer's code added after that. Starting from the original fiddle and adding the code will yield what you find on vevo. [link](http://jsfiddle.net/z9Unk/229/) Yes, this can break if you mouseover then out and over again. But that's a different question, if you can't figure it out.